# The specified initialization script '/tmp/ijresolvers.gradle' does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Linux Mint 20.1

In IntelIJ 2020  I import SpringBoot gradle project.

here my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.gmail.myproject
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And from terminal I success run spring boot project:

```
./gradlew bootrun
```

Nice.

Now I want to run project from IntelIJ. But I get error:

```
11:23:24 AM: Executing task...


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The specified initialization script '/tmp/ijresolvers.gradle' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10ms
11:23:24 AM: Task execution finished.
```

Comment: Seems there is not enough rights on "/tmp" folder for IDE process.

Answer (score 8):

Deleting the `/home/[YOUR_USERNAME]/.gradle` worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue as you, thankfully as it is a /tmp/ folder issue, all you need to do is restart your system. I just rebooted and the problem was gone.

Comment: Your answer seems simple and not very technical. but saved my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error but access to '/tmp' was not the reason. Idea tried to import project w/o SDK set. Below worked for me

1. Set SDK (ctrl-alt-shift-s)
2. !! Unlink gradle project in gradle tab
3. Reload gradle project again.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with intellij running via flatpak. Downloading intellij from jetbrains and running directly fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: use JDK < 16 in "Project SDK".